# Why is firmware implementation not preferred for more lfsr based encryption schemes?

Tags: encryption, lfsr

Given that an algorithmic implementation of a linear feedback shift register based encryption scheme is (much?) more secure against side channel attacks; why are hardware platforms usually used?

I get that speed is a factor in stream/block cipher systems used in communication protocols ie. error correction or encryption. However, say, authentication systems such as used to unlock cars etc. have no requirement for ultra fast responses. Would not building these in hardware using flip flops etc. open them up to SCAs?

Comment: Trivium? Well, if my car key is in the hand of someone, there is no need to side-channel. What is the real problem here?

Comment: Also, if we're talking about car keys, a significant factor is cost (when you're making 100 million of the devices and save one cent on each one, you've just saved a million dollars).  The only thing that those keys do is the authentication; the circuitry to do the flipflops might be smaller than a tiny CPU to do that same operation in software.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and maybe car keys was not a good example. A better one could be the entry system to a bank vault, or other secure building. In all cases the attacker would have to get hold of your key, recover the secret and then return the key.